# If $f$ is continuously differentiable periodic, then $n\int_{0}^{1} f(x) \sin (2\pi nx) \mathrm dx \to 0 $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

If $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is continuously differentiable periodic function of period $1$, then 
$$n\int_{0}^{1} f(x) \sin(2\pi nx)\mathrm dx \to 0 $$
as $ n\to\infty$.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma?

Comment: yea , in that lemma  we take f as a L1 integrable function,  right? how it work now in our problem?

Comment: The idea was to apply it to $f'$. I think it's in the answer below now. :)

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**. You may integrate by parts:
$$
\begin{align}
&n\int_{0}^{1} f(x) \sin(2\pi n x)\: dx\\\\
&=\left. -f(x)\frac{\cos(2\pi n x)}{2\pi}\right|_0^1+\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^1f'(x)\cos(2\pi n x)\:dx\\\\
&=\frac{f(0)-f(1)}{2\pi}+\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^1f'(x)\cos(2\pi n x)\:dx\\\\
&=0+\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^1f'(x)\cos(2\pi n x)\:dx \to 0
\end{align}
$$ as $n \to \infty$, using the [Riemann-Lebesgue lemma](http://n.ethz.ch/~lukaswi/download/WS0506/MMP1/solution9-2.pdf).

Comment: Thank you @ olivier it's really good proof

Comment: @SaritaSharma You are welcome!

Comment: @SaritaSharma : In case you are not aware, you can choose to accept the answer, that basically "finishes" the post. (Others will then see it in the front page and do you need to click into the post)